# Android Emulator setup for window 10 using cordova command line?

Tags: cordova, android-studio, android-emulator

I wanted to load Android  code into  Emulator devices using cordova command line after creating android platform (`cordova platform add android`)

ie `cordova run android`

> But i could not find any Android SDK manager (.exe file) as most recent are zip files. Older version SDK manager
>   does not  support properly with latest version of cordova as well. Is
>   there any way i can run Android Emulator on windows. I have installed
>   Android studio with sdk manager as well, but dont know how can i run
>   emulator from Adb command line. Highly appreciate for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to load Android Emulator devices for testing purpose myself after hours of googling using Cordova command line.
Provided installed Android studio with a created Emulator.

1. > list available Emulator and choose the Emulator name to start by going
   >   to this 
   >   directory
   >
   > C:\Users\marts\android\sdk\tools\bin>

   and execute below command to list all available emulator and select
   one .

   ```
      avdmanager list avd
   ```

   In my case i have selected Nexus_6P_API_27
2. > Start that Emulator by going to below  directory and launch named
   >   Emulator using below command
   >
   > C:\Users\name\android\sdk\emulator

   ```
      emulator -avd  Nexus_6P_API_27
   ```

And then run cordova command 
`cordova run android`  after creating android platform